# belongsTo App\User возвращает только id laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Нужно получить экземпляр пользователя с помощью:

```
    public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'user');
}
```

Но функция возвращает только id пользователя.

App\User:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'avatar', 'steamid64', 'steamid'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, у вас перепутаны аргументы в методе `belongsTo` (хотя это проблему не решит). Правильно будет:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user', 'id');
}
```

Во-вторых, проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к атрибуту-методу `user`, в то время как у вас уже есть в модели атрибут-число `user`.

**Решение 1.** Назвать метод для связи с `User::class` иначе, например, `owner`:

```
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user', 'id');
}
```

Тогда

```
$someObject->owner // будет содержать объект App\User.
```

**Решение 2**. Переименовать столбец в модели связанного объекта с `user` на `user_id`, как это и рекомендуется в Laravel.

```
// в файле миграции модели
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
```

и тогда уже заработает обращение к `$someObject->user` будет содержать объект `App\User`.